# renaming files in a directory + subdirectories in python

Tags: python

I have some files that I'm working with in a python script. The latest requirement is that I go into a directory that the files will be placed in and rename all files by adding a datestamp and project name to the beginning of the filename while keeping the original name.

i.e. foo.txt becomes 2011-12-28_projectname_foo.txt

Building the new tag was easy enough, it's just the renaming process that's tripping me up.

Comment: Have you looked at [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: It would be easier to rename the directory... so it could direct you (your manager) to the correct project / date... without the need to make it overly difficult for anyone to find anything in the directory by naming everything almost identically.

Comment: no, it wouldn't. there's a need for the files to be named like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older post of mine, but seeing as how it's been viewed quite a few times I figure I'll post what I did to resolve this.

```
import os

sv_name="(whatever it's named)"
today=datetime.date.today()
survey=sv_name.replace(" ","_")
date=str(today).replace(" ","_")
namedate=survey+str(date)

[os.rename(f,str(namedate+"_"+f)) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

Answer (score 7):

Can you post what you have tried?

I think you should just need to use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) with [os.rename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename).

Something like this:

```
import os
from os.path import join

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/dir'):
    for name in files:
        newname = foo + name
        os.rename(join(root,name),join(root,newname))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os

dir_name = os.path.realpath('ur directory')

cnt=0  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        cnt=cnt+1
        file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]#file name no ext
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        dir_name = os.path.basename(root)
        try: 
            os.rename(root+"/"+file,root+"/"+dir_name+extension)
        except FileExistsError: 
            os.rename(root+"/"+file,root+""+dir_name+str(cnt)+extension)
```

to care if more files are there in single folder and if we need to give incremental value for the files